# mutt: move IMAP folder

Tags: mutt, imap

Can an IMAP folder be moved within `mutt`? If one navigates to the list of folders (`c?`), the default key bindings allow one to create a new mailbox (`C`), change mailbox/folder (`c`), delete a mailbox (`d`), or rename a mailbox (`r`). However, I don't know how to move an existing folder to another folder (thereby becoming a subfolder of the destination folder) or to move a subfolder up one or more levels in the directory structure (e.g., `mv folder ..`). How can these move operations be performed?

Answer (score 2):

Mutt supports directory components in the path you give when you rename (`r`). To move `=dir1/dir2/dir3` to `dir1`, you can do the following:

1. Type `c<Tab>` to invoke the folder browser.
2. Navigate to `dir2` and select `dir3`.
3. Type `r`. Enter `dir1/dir3`.

I'm not sure I understand the specification of the destination path. `..` doesn't behave like I'd expect it too. Special variables like `=` don't either.

Answer (score 1):

You just rename it, but IMAP's folder structure isn't the same as the UNIX filesystem.  It *can* be implemented that way, but it often isn't.  The hierarchy is often emulated as a bunch of folders in one directory with the name reflecting the hierarchy getting there.

So I have a folder `Computers` with a subfolder `Servers`.  When I go to rename the Servers folder `mutt` shows it's current name (for me to change) as `Computers.Servers`.  If I change it just to `Servers`, suddenly the folder is moved to the "root" of my mail folders.